# CSS Styling Issue for different sized images with different background sizes

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a bunch of icons that I am using. Each icon png is a square (100px x 100px), however, that includes whitespace (the white background of the png). Some of these icons within the pngs are only 50px x 50px, while some are 100px x 100px, and others are also different heights and widths... but overall, EVERY png is 100px x 100px.

I am trying to use these as icons, but when I have them on the page, the whitespace is transparent, so some of the icons are the correct size (100px x 100px), and some of them are small.

How can I fix this with css?

Here is an example of the code:

```
<div className="parent">
  <img className="image" src="icon.png"
</div>
```

What would the css be? i've tried tons of different solutions with failure.

```
.parent {

}

.image {

}
```

Comment: Please go through the following link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Howto/Fill_a_box_with_an_image

Hope this will help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in Css file

```
.box img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.box1 img {
 object-fit: cover;
}

.box2 img {
 object-fit: contain;
}

.box3 img {
 object-fit: fill;
}
```

and like this in JS file

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box box1"><img src="balloon.jpg" alt="a balloon"></div>
    <div class="box box2"><img src="balloon.jpg" alt="a balloon"></div>
    <div class="box box3"><img src="balloon.jpg" alt="a balloon"></div>
</div>
```

hope this works and solves your problem